# Model that predict both categorical and numerical output

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, data-modeling, modeling

I am building a RNN for a time series model, which have a categorical output.
For example, if precious 3 pattern is "A","B","A","B" model predict next is "A".
there's also a numerical level associated with each category.
For example A is 100, B is 50, 
so A(100), B(50), A(100), B(50),
I have the model framework to predict next is "A", it would be nice to predict the (100) at the same time.

For real life examples, you have national weather data.
You are predicting the next few days weather type(Sunny, windy, raining ect...) at the same time, it would be nice model will also predict the temperature.

Or for Amazon, analysis customer's trxns pattern.
Customer A shopped category
electronic($100), household($10), ... ...
predict what next trxn category that this customer is likely to shop and predict at the same time what would be the amount of that trxns.

Researched a bit, have not found any relevant research on similar topics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because higher-level statistics and modeling questions belong on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

What is stopping you from adding an extra output to your model? You could have one categorical output and one numerical output next to each other. Every neural network library out there supports multiple outputs.

Your will need to normalise your output data though. Categories should be normalised with *one-hot encoding* and numerical values should be normalised by dividing by some maximal value.

> Researched a bit, have not found any relevant research on similar topics.

Because this is not really a 'topic'. This is something completely normal, and it does not require some special kind of network.

Comment: because typically the output function can only be 1. for cross_entryphy which predict categorical. or other regression function to predict numerical output.

Comment: @HuaYe not per se 'typically'. You just have to configure your network to have a seperate output which is not linked with the categorical classifcation. If you're not sure how to configure this, you could also create a second recurrent network that takes the input from the categorical network, and then computes the numerical value. But it would be more useful to plug them in togetehr.

Comment: it's not how to configure the output, it's the configuration itself only allow 1 output function. you can use it 1 function to predict both, but it would not make sense to do that way.  I have not come across any configuration that allow 2 output function. Yes you can always build a second model to do those 2 things, but it's off the topic

Comment: @HuaYe It's not the configuration itself to only allow 1 output function. There is no such thing as an 'output function',  you are talking about an output layer, with multipe output nodes (each representing a categorical label). Maybe you should switch to another neural network library if your current one doesn't allow side outputs. Or if you can't find a suitable one, code your OWN neural network. Becuase what you want is something that already exists.

Comment: @HuaYe you can always remove the softmax layer on the last layer, and add in an extra input for the numerical value. Afterwards you write a small function which does the softmax function on the categorical outputs yourself.